# How to get WP7 Panorama Content from another xaml- File?

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, panorama-control

First I have to make clear what i am Trying to accomplish, it's going to be an app where I have 4 Panoramas, the first Page on every Panorama is different. But the last 3 Pages are identical.

Is it anyhow possible not to define these 3 Pages in every Panorama? Can I define the Content in an XAML File and load it into the Panoramas? So if i have changes i dont have to make them on 4 different Pages...

I hope you understood my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the simplest way is to put the contents of each of the identical pages into UserControls, and reference the UserControls in the panorama items.

**EDIT: Example**

Current situation:

```
<controls:Panorama Title="my application">
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
        <!-- Your Panorama Item Content -->
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="second item">
        <!--  Item Content To Be Moved -->
        <TextBlock Text="ToBeMovedToUserControl"/>  
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Now put the contents of the repeating panorama items in a UserControl:
Add a new UserControl in Visual Studio (select "UserControl" from the item templates), and 
add the XAML that you currently have in the PanoraItem:

```
<UserControl x:Class="PanoramaApp1.WindowsPhoneControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
         <TextBlock Text="ToBeMovedToUserControl"/>  
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and change the panorama XAML to:

```
<controls:Panorama Title="my application">
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="first item">
        <!-- Your Panorama Item Content -->
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
    <controls:PanoramaItem Header="second item">
        <!--  Item Content To Be Moved -->
        <WindowsPhoneControl1/>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

Note that you may have to inlcude a namespace definition in the page containing the panorama so that the control can be found.

Comment: +1 I was going to answer the same. Seems the most logic way to do this.. :)

Comment: can you give me a small example please? i am pretty new to silverlight and these controlls...

Comment: @AytacAkyol: Added a primitive example.

Answer (score 0):

add the panoramaitem dynamically in the .cs